# JDK API location on OSX Lion

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-lion, javadoc

I am trying to add the Javadoc location in Eclipse Helios on OSX Lion 10.7.3. I just installed the Java for Developers 2012-01 from Apple.

I have the following problem: There is no src.jar/docs.jar file in my Java install folder (/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home).

Did they remove it from the installation? What can I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the JDK on Mac does not include src.jar.
You need to download and install "Java Developer Package" from [Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).
After installation you will find src.jar under a path similar to this

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Then on that folder you will find the src.jar

Comment: My installation was upgrades only yesterday to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_26-b03-383.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar`...

Comment: Yes, naturally the folder changes for different version.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!! I knew this dmg existed, but it is _impossible_ to find by searching Google!

Answer (score 1):

The default "user" downloads of Java from Apple don't include the sources or Javadoc. You can download a special Java Developer package for installation from https://connect.apple.com/. You'll have to register with Apple with an Apple Id, but the free account is enough to download the developer package, no need for a full, costly ADC membership.
The good thing about the developer packages is also that they don't overwrite each other, so you can install multiple versions to test your software with.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, mavenise your project, install m2e and let maven download the sources  (right click -> maven -> download sources). The advantage being you can download sources for all libraries in additions to the jdk